# Pass authentication object from filter to provider in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to add a custom parameter to authentication object. So I create a wrapper for Authentication object which contains custom parameter. Then create this object in `CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthnticationFilter {
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(...){
        Authentication auth = super.attemptAuthentication(...);
        CustomAuthentication custAuth = new CustomAuthentication(auth);
        custAuth.setCustomParameter("");
        return custAuth;
    }
}
```

Then in `CustomAuthenticationProvider` I get Authentication object and want to cast it to `CustomAuthentication`. This throws `ClassCastException`. Isn't the object passed to `CustomAuthenticationProvider` the same which I created in `CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Here is my Spring Security Config -

```
<sec:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" auto-config="false"> ... <sec:custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/> </sec:http>
```

Comment: Can you show how you have set-up Spring security to use the `CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Comment: <sec:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" auto-config="false">
 ...
 <sec:custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
                           position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
</sec:http>

Comment: The answer is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` inside `attemptAuthentication(...)` 

1) creates UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

2) calls `getAuthenticationManager.authenticate()` which in turn calls `provider.authenticate()`.

So if one tries to redefine Authentication object, he should override `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication()` method and extract all http parameters himself.

It is more handy to use token.details field to add custom parameters to authentication object by extending default details object and DetailsSource object.

Comment: Comprised some of SpringSecurity in [detail here](http://techastute.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-security-in-detail.html), may be its useful for some one.